# Keep detection of value selected in radio button

Tags: jquery

This code below throws an alert when loaded, because it detects that the second radio button is checked. But if I select the first one, and then select the second one again, the alert is not thrown..why?

http://jsfiddle.net/h6j58/3/

```
<input type="radio" id="s530351a84b2aa_tipo_0" name="radioName" required="required" value="0"  >
<input type="radio" id="s530351a84b2aa_tipo_1" name="radioName" required="required" value="1" checked="checked">

$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("input[name=radioName]:checked").val() == 1)
    {
    alert("fajslf");    
    }
});
```

Comment: You forgot to fire `change()`

Comment: because you have to set a `change` event but you are trying to get it on doc ready.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you don't capture any events, just checking if your certain radion is checked on `document load`. You need to capture `change` event of your radio buttons like in following code:

```
$("input[name=radioName]").on("change", function () {
    if($("input[name=radioName]:checked").val() == 1)
    {
        alert("fajslf");    
    }
});
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h6j58/5/)

Comment: @ziiweb put `$("input[name=radioName]").trigger('change');` code line in your `$(document).ready()` function

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using this `if` statement as soon as your `document` is `ready`. You need to add in a `change` event handler to detect changes made to the radio element.

```
$("input[name=radioName]").on("change", function () {
    if (this.checked && this.value === "1")
    {
        alert("fajslf");    
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h6j58/8/).

> I mean it should throw the alert also when the page is just loaded.

In this situation you can move the check into a separate function. Here I've called this function `checkRadio` which takes an element as its only argument:

```
function checkRadio(elem) {
    // If this element has a value of 1 and is checked, alert
    if (elem.value === "1" && elem.checked)
        alert("fajslf");
}

// On radio change function, call checkRadio
$("input[name=radioName]").on("change", function () {
    checkRadio(this);
});

// Call checkRadio on document ready, passing in the radio with value of 1
checkRadio($('input[name=radioName][value=1]')[0]);
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h6j58/11/).

Comment: thanks, but now it throws the alert when I click on the radio button, but when I load the page, the radio button is already selected, how to check that? I mean it should throw the alert also when the page is just loaded.

Comment: @ziiweb separate the check out into a function. http://jsfiddle.net/h6j58/11/ I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/h6j58/6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=radioName]').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 1)
    {
    alert("fajslf");    
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Not sure why this received more upvotes than the other answers here. `this.value` should be used instead of `$(this).val()` and there's nothing in here to check whether the radio is checked.

Comment: I never said it did have a bug. I said that you're using `$(this).val()` which is bad practice, and you're not actually checking whether the radio button is checked like OP's code does.

Answer (score 0):

edit your code like this :

```
$(".testValue").change(function(){
    if($("input[name=radioName]:checked").val() == 1)
    {
    alert("fajslf");    
    } 
});
```

and addClass your input.

Checkt it FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/h6j58/7/

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h6j58/9/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=radioName]").click(function() {

       if($(this).prop('checked') && $(this).val() == 1)
        {
            alert("fajslf");    
       }   
    });
});
```

Comment: If this radio button added dynamically in your page then use Jquery "on()" method.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This Way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[name=radioName]:checked').change(function () {

                alert("alert statements...");

        });
    });
```